# which mp3 engine does the flash player plugin using?

Tags: flash, plugins, mp3

What is the mp3 playing engine does flash player web plugin is using ?

Comment: Why do you need to know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Flash Player's [3rd party software page](http://www.adobe.com/products/eula/third_party/flashplayer/11/) reports "technology licensed by Fraunhofer IIS and Thomson Multimedia", but I don't think you're likely to find any more details than that. (And note that Flash could use different libraries on different platforms or versions - all that's guaranteed to content is that the APIs stay consistent.)